# Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Encryption::hash() in codeigniter 3.1.9

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

After upgrade codeigniter 2.1.4 to 3.1.9 we have issue.

**Question 1:**
`$this->encryption->hash($this->input->post('password'));`
this code working on codeigniter 2.1.4.

we upgrade codeigniter 2.1.4 to 3.1.9 after that return `Call to undefined method CI_Encryption::hash()` this error.

**Question 2:**
also,I have one error `$this->encryption->encrypt()` this code not working but it return encrypt string is to long (string length 128).in codeigniter 2.1.4 it working proper.

Comment: `hash` has been moved to `encrypt` and is not a static member.

Comment: yes, i understand issue about 'hash' and resolved it. thank you.

Comment: but, i don't solve second issue. can we help me?